# How to host WCF Data Service in ASP.Net MVC3 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf-data-services

I have written several WCF data services and find them quite useful. However, I have found routing to be quite a pain. I have seen conversations that indicate that you can host a data service in an ASP.Net MVC app (I have always used ASP.Net web sites). However, I do not seem to be able to find any examples of how to achieve this. Does anybody have any references I could check-out or advice?

Answer (score 2):

The question was posted some time ago but I assume there are still people interested in using WCF Data Services in ASP.NET MVC projects.

Assuming that you have in your project a service called: 'DataSourceService.svc' you can use this service in an MVC project by configuring the routing in 'RouteConfig.cs' as follows:

```
using System.Data.Services;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace <YourNamespace>
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                // the controller should NOT contain "DataSourceService"
                constraints: new { controller = "^((?!(DataSourceService)).)*$" }
            );

            routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("DataSourceService", new DataServiceHostFactory(), typeof(DataSourceService)));

        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have in Web.config the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Now you can check that everything works fine by running your project in the  browser and using the following url:

http://localhost:port_number/DataSourceService/$metadata

... which should return your metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The WCF web api may do what you're looking for. Here's their [getting started page](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started%3a%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api). You host the service inside of the MVC app, and even hook into into the same routing that MVC uses.

Comment: The question is specifically about WCF Data Services, which works differently than SOAP based WCF services. I'm not sure that your answer applies to their question.

Comment: Thanks for you advice. Unfortunately, from what I can determine, @M. is correct. this does not work for Data Services.